# Is it possible to reserialize using powershell script? ps1

Tags: unicorn

With this method https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/5588/1360, we can sync the content from FileSystem to Sitecore DB.

Can we do the reverse? DB to FileSystem using something like

```
"Reserialize-Unicorn -ControlPanelUrl 'http://sc82u5.local/unicorn.aspx' -SharedSecret '4DED97FE-32B0-4F0A-AFD8-1CA3229C74F5' -Configurations @('Content')"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the powershell functions you're looking for are:

```
# Reserialize one

Export-UnicornConfiguration "Foundation.Foo"

# Reserialize multiple by name

Export-UnicornConfiguration @("Foundation.Foo", "Foundation.Bar")

# Reserialize from pipeline

Get-UnicornConfiguration "Foundation.*" | Export-UnicornConfiguration
```

Taken from [here](https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/02/Unicorn-4-Preview-Part-2-SPE-Support/)

EDIT: that's for the Sitecore powershell way of doing things. If you want to use the old standard powershell API - I believe you can just add `-Verb 'Reserialize'` to the parameters.

E.g.

```
Sync-Unicorn -ControlPanelUrl 'https://localhost/unicorn.aspx' -SharedSecret 'your-sharedsecret-here' -Verb 'Reserialize'
```